# Shadow of parallax image in overflow parent

Tags: jquery, position, parallax

I have a jquery animation. I have a parent div, it has some children divs. The parent div has overflow hidden, and an outer shadow.

The children divs are larger and taller than the parent div (for the parallax effect), they have the same cover positioned backgrounds, and all move the same way (one div is for the image, one for the fancybox gallery, one for a blur effect). Let's consider now only the image child div.

When I animate the parent div from screen to down, or back, it has a speed, the children speed is different and I transform the translate Y position (but I will do later with other parent divs X position also) of the children.

My problem is that when I make the animation, as there is a timing offset between the parent and children divs, the parent div will have a small part where it is empty, but because of its shadow, the visual effect is stupid.

I was thinking to create an empty div and place it under/out of the parent div, give the shadow for it, not for the parent div. This shadow div should have the same size and position as the visual part of the children divs of the parent div, and it would move also together with the children divs. So the visual part of the child div should be calculated and apply that size and position to the shadow div.

I had some source of codes, but they do not work.

HTML:

```
<div class="scene scene1">
  <div class="i">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="fancy"></div>
    <div class="blur"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="shadow"></div> -->
  <div class="b b1">Slide Down</div>
</div>

<div class="scene scene2">
  <div class="i">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="fancy"></div>
    <div class="blur"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="shadow"></div> -->
  <div class="b b2">Slide Back</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.scene {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scene:before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('http://www.igorlaszlo.com/photography/img/portfolio/ma1.jpg') 50% 50%/80% no-repeat;
    opacity:0.3;
}

.scene1 {
    top: 0;
}

.scene2 {
    top: 101%;
}

.i {
    position: absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    transition: transform 4s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1) 0.3s;
}

.blur {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    filter: blur(6px);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: transform 4s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1) 0.3s;
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 100%, 50% 100%);
}

.i .blur.forhide {
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
    animation: blur-hide 4s forwards 1.5s;
}
@keyframes blur-hide {
  0% { clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%); }
  100% { clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 100%, 50% 100%); }
}

.i .blur.forshow {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 100%, 50% 100%);
    animation: blur-show 4s forwards 1.5s;
}
@keyframes blur-show {
  0% { clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 100%, 50% 100%); }
  100% { clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%); }
}

.shadow {
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.b {
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    width: 5%;
    height: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.scene1 .i {
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    width: 30%;
    height: 35%;
}

.scene1 .img, .scene1 .blur {
    background-image: url('http://www.igorlaszlo.com/photography/img/portfolio/ma1.jpg');
    aspect-ratio: 1.5/1;
    height: 200%;
}

/*.scene1 .shadow {
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    width: 30%;
    height: 35%;
}*/

.scene2 .i {
    top: 80%;
    left: 35%;
    width: 15%;
    height: 45%;
}

.scene2 .img, .scene2 .blur {
    background-image: url('http://www.igorlaszlo.com/photography/img/portfolio/ma2.jpg');
    aspect-ratio: 1/1.5;
    height: 200%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

/*.scene2 .shadow {
    top: 80%;
    left: 35%;
    width: 15%;
    height: 45%;
}*/


.b1 {
    top:0;
}
.b2 {
    top:20%;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /*$(".img").each(function() {
        var childOffset = $(this).offset();
        var parentOffset = $(".i").offset();
    
        var childWidth = $(this).width();
        var childHeight = $(this).height();
    
        var visibleWidth = Math.min(childOffset.left + childWidth, parentOffset.left + $(".i").width()) - Math.max(childOffset.left, parentOffset.left);
        var visibleHeight = Math.min(childOffset.top + childHeight, parentOffset.top + $(".i").height()) - Math.max(childOffset.top, parentOffset.top);

        $(this).data("visibleWidth", visibleWidth);
        $(this).data("visibleHeight", visibleHeight);
  });
  
    var shadowWidth = 0;
    var shadowHeight = 0;
  
    $(".img").each(function() {
        shadowWidth = Math.max(shadowWidth, $(this).data("visibleWidth"));
        shadowHeight = Math.max(shadowHeight, $(this).data("visibleHeight"));
    });
  
    $(".shadow").css({
        width: shadowWidth,
        height: shadowHeight
    });*/

    $('.b1').click(function(){
        $('.scene1').delay(300).animate({'top':'-101vh'}, 4000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        $('.scene1 .i, .scene1 .shadow').delay(300).animate({'top':'-40%'}, 4000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        $('.scene1 .i .img, .scene1 .i .blur').css({'transform':'translate(-50%,-100%)','transition':'transform 4s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1)'});
        $('.scene1 .i .blur').removeClass('forhide').addClass('forshow');
        $('.scene2').delay(300).animate({'top':0}, 4000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        $('.scene2 .i, .scene2 .shadow').delay(300).animate({'top':'30%'}, 4000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        $('.scene2 .i .img, .scene2 .i .blur').css({'transform':'translate(-50%,-50%)','transition':'transform 4s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1) 1s'});
        $('.scene2 .i .blur').removeClass('forshow').addClass('forhide');
    });
    
    $('.b2').click(function(){
        $('.scene1').delay(300).animate({'top':0}, 4000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        $('.scene1 .i, .scene1 .shadow').delay(300).animate({'top':'10%'}, 4000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        $('.scene1 .i .img, .scene1 .i .blur').css({'transform':'translate(-50%,-50%)','transition':'transform 4s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1) 1s'});
        $('.scene1 .i .blur').delay(1500).removeClass('forshow').addClass('forhide');
        $('.scene2').delay(300).animate({'top':'101vh'}, 4000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        $('.scene2 .i, .scene2 .shadow').delay(300).animate({'top':'80%'}, 4000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        $('.scene2 .i .img, .scene2 .i .blur').css({'transform':'translate(-50%,0%)','transition':'transform 4s cubic-bezier(0.76, 0, 0.24, 1)'});
        $('.scene2 .i .blur').removeClass('forhide').addClass('forshow');
    });
    
});
```

You can see a jsfiddle here (I did not delete, just disabled some codes to show with what I was trying as a solution) : [https://jsfiddle.net/igorlaszlo/fxg4qmkj/14/](https://jsfiddle.net/igorlaszlo/fxg4qmkj/13/)

Here I tried to explain also on an image, because English is not my mother tongue. :

[image]

Please try to be simple/clear, because I do webdesign as a hobby for my own personal websites, and also because of my English.